# Image text wrap not working properly on frontend

Tags: images

I've been tearing my hair out trying to get this fixed. I can't figure out what's going wrong. It looks fine in the Visual Editor (though I usually use the text version instead - and NEVER use Gutenburg (so this is referencing the Classic Editor).

Images aligned left or right just do not properly wrap the text. I have added the following CSS to my stylesheet, and it makes no difference.

```
.alignnone {
    margin: 5px 20px 20px 0;
}

.aligncenter,
div.aligncenter {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto 5px auto;
}

.alignright {
    float:right;
    margin: 5px 0 20px 20px;
}

.alignleft {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 20px 20px 0;
}

a img.alignright {
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 0 20px 20px;
}

a img.alignnone {
    margin: 5px 20px 20px 0;
}

a img.alignleft {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 20px 20px 0;
}

a img.aligncenter {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

It wraps only with the paragraph it was added next to. But subsequent paragraphs do not continue the wrap. They start below the image, as seen in this screenshot:
[image]

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Your issue may be with the paragraph css. Can you share a link?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. But this is the css for p `p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}`

Comment: We just need more context. I've reproduced your code in a CodePen here and it works: https://codepen.io/friendlywp/pen/abdwMew

Comment: Is it possible to provide a link via PM? I don't actually know how to do that here.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't appear that it's possible to send a PM or do a private comment, so I'll post the dev link to the particular page in question: [link]http://reason4rhymes.themedev.thepixelpixie.com/welcome-to-my-blog/[/link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container `div` for the content area has a class of `.row`, which is set to `display:flex` in Bootstrap. Direct children of a parent with `display:flex` can't be floated.

To fix this you'll either need to update the `.row` class so it's not set to `display:flex` (`display:block` works for me), or add an interior wrapper div so that the image and paragraphs not direct children of the `.row` div.

Comment: Wow. I honestly never would have known about the issue with display: flex. That fixed it right up. Thank you SO SO much!

Comment: @LauraSage Fantastic! So glad that worked. If you're good to go, can you mark this as the correct answer? Thank you!